# How to simulate a "open link on new window" on a C# WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I just found out that to simulate a click I can call `element.InvokeMember("click");` where `element` is an `HtmlElement`. But what I actually need is to open the link in a new window, but not on the default browser but on another `WebBrowser` I would create in my program. Sometimes it works to just get the href attribute by calling `element.GetAttribute("href");` and then just navigating to the returned URL, but some picky web pages won't work this way, I assume something to do with cookies and sessions.

Comment: OK, this could be solved some other way: if I can clone the content of a WebBrowser I could follow the link on the clone. I could also just reload the current URL, but that can be messy on for some cases. There might be a way to just clone the whole thing on the same state as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just handle the NewWindow2 event, create a form/tab that has a webbrowser on it, and use the webbrowser as the target of the new window request. Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` is a very crippled control and one of its biggest problem - supporting of multi-tabbing. It doesn't support it at all.

I spent tons of time to try make it work properly but got no sufficient success, so recommend you to try 3rd party control instead.

Workaround: subscribe to click event of each `<a>` on page (or some of them you need) and create a new windows manually. For example, see how does it implemented in dotBrowser: [1](http://dotbrowser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dotbrowser/trunk/MainForm/frmMain.Browser.cs?revision=51&view=markup#l90) [2](http://dotbrowser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dotbrowser/trunk/MainForm/frmMain.ContextMenu.cs?revision=51&view=markup#l227)

```
foreach (HtmlElement tag in webBrowser.Document.All)
{
    tag.Id = String.Empty;
    switch (tag.TagName.ToUpper())
    {
        case "A":
        {
            tag.MouseUp += new HtmlElementEventHandler(link_MouseUp);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void link_MouseUp(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass a = (mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass)((HtmlElement)sender).DomElement;
    switch (e.MouseButtonsPressed)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
        {
            // open new tab
            break;
        }
        case MouseButtons.Right:
        {
            // open context menu
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But, what would be the code in the "// open new tab" line, since that's where you actually open the link in a new window?

Comment: @jsoldi: Follow link #2 above. Me in your case - would create a new form with constructor accepting a string (url). That form would create a new WebBrowser and navigate it to that url.

Comment: Well, the problem with that is that some pages uses cookies and stuff like that that won't let me just copy the link and open it on a new window. That's what I was doing before until I found out that on ebay, copying the href of the "Next" link (the one that would send me to the next page of results) and then navigating to it in a new window would land me always on the first page. No idea why. I suspect it has something to do with sessions and cookies.